# Please help me understand this script within a .ascx web user control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The following is found within a .ascx web user control, and I'm trying to figure out where I would find "localtable_" and what the last line is doing.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClickTable(me)
    {
        var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
            for(n = 0; n < tables.length; n++)
                if(tables[n].id.indexOf("localtable_") > -1)
                    tables[n].className = "";
        me.className = "CommitteeTableBackground";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Apparently there are multiple <table>s in the page and they are expected to have id starting with localtable_.

Answer (score 0):

Try view source of the Page from the Browser where the user control is used. It should give you all the tables starting with localtable_ Ids.

1. The script is setting the class names of all tables with Ids that start with  "localtable_" to empty.
2. Setting the current table class name to CommitteeTableBackground. May be this done to highlight only the currently selected class.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just am trying to figure out the reasoning behind this, since there are so many other moving parts involved. We use an iMIS (AMS) database and somewhere these tables are pulling information and rendering them with particular information. The issue is that there are a few entries that should not be displayed, but I can't figure out the reasons why.